# How to access POST data in Symfony Validator with Datatranformer?

Tags: php, validation, symfony, http-post

I'm having trouble understanding how to use Symfony Form Validation in this case:

I'm working on a Form that saves chemical Compounds, using the chemical Formula as String input. That input, such as "H2O", is DataTransformed to a Collection of chemical Elements ("H","H","O") which is saved together with a newly generated String representation ("H2O") as Formula. That ensures validity of the Formula and that e.g. "OH2" can't be saved, since the automatic generation of the Formula takes those issues into account and changes it into "H2O". I don't want to have public access to Compound->setFormula() as that will lead to inconsistency with the included Elements.

Now, I want to make sure an input such as "H2Oxxxx" is not being saved as "H2O" without noticing the input actually differs from the found Formula, whereas "OH2" should be accepted and saved as "H2O". I'm trying to use a Constraint "isValidCompound" and a Validator "isValidCompoundValidator" for that. The (simple?) question is now: How to access the POST data from isValidCompoundValidator in order to compare the automatically created Formula with it? Usually, you could just access it using $compound->getFormula(), because it is automatically filled with the Form data. In my case, it is only filled by using the found Elements for the reasons given above.

Does that setup make sense at all and should I just try to access the POST data directly using $request->request->all();? Or is a different setup of classes preferable?

Thanks alot!